# Affix is not working in Bootstrap 4 (alpha)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix, bootstrap-4

According to Bootstrap 3 docs I have added following attributes to a navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar no-margin-bottom" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="90" >
...
</nav>
```

After scrolling down the page Bootstrap 4 is not adding class to navbar which is affix. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Bootstrap.js and jQuery.js are working.

Comment: Have you read the Bootstrap 4 docs? If you do, and this is specified in Bootstrap 4 docs, you can create an issue [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev)

Comment: @jamie You mean the affix plugin is dropped?

Comment: @jamie if affix is dropped how we can do things like as affix do?

Comment: See @vucko's answer. I haven't even checked the docs or used Bootstrap 4... just to remind you of a way. *See Vucko's answer for further details.*

Comment: LoL i just lost an whole hour when try to figure out why affix is not working... It seems that page I get to work on used boostrap v4 and not v3... From now I will always check if page is using "standard" versions, not some "latest new futures" :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although the affix is removed from Bootstrap in version 4. However, you can achieve your goal through this jQuery Code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollValue == settings.scrollTopPx || scrollValue > 70) {
         $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
    } 
});
```

Comment: I assume `$('.navbar').addClass('navbar');` is supposed to be `$('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');`? I don't see how adding a class that it already has would do anything, otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

**Update Bootstrap 4**

The docs recommend the sticky polyfill, and the recommended ScrollPos-Styler doesn't really help with scroll position (you can easily define an offset).

I think it's **easier** to use jQuery to watch the window scroll and change the CSS accordingly to fixed...

```
  var toggleAffix = function(affixElement, wrapper, scrollElement) {

    var height = affixElement.outerHeight(),
        top = wrapper.offset().top;

    if (scrollElement.scrollTop() >= top){
        wrapper.height(height);
        affixElement.addClass("affix");
    }
    else {
        affixElement.removeClass("affix");
        wrapper.height('auto');
    }

  };


  $('[data-toggle="affix"]').each(function() {
    var ele = $(this),
        wrapper = $('<div></div>');

    ele.before(wrapper);
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
        toggleAffix(ele, wrapper, $(this));
    });

    // init
    toggleAffix(ele, wrapper, $(window));
  });
```

[Bootstrap 4 affix (sticky navbar)](http://codeply.com/go/LDHQhWUG0x)

**EDIT:** Another solution is to use this [port of the 3.x Affix plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/affix) as a replacement in Bootstrap 4..

http://www.codeply.com/go/HmY7DLHLkI

---

Related: [Animate/Shrink NavBar on scroll using Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4/42250478#42250478)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. It also works with scrollspy.

Answer (score 13):

[From the bootstrap v4 documentation:](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components)

> **Dropped** the Affix jQuery plugin. We recommend using a `position: sticky` polyfill instead. [See the HTML5 Please entry](http://html5please.com/#sticky) for details and specific polyfill recommendations.
>
> > If you were using Affix to apply additional, non-`position` styles, the polyfills might not support your use case. One option for such uses is the third-party [ScrollPos-Styler](https://github.com/acch/scrollpos-styler) library.

Comment: important: `position: sticky` does not work in chrome yet cause it's only has been 4 years since it was introduced...

Comment: @clankill3r Only... :-P FYI it used to work in Chrome until they broke it.

Answer (score 4):

To build on Anwar Hussain's answer. I found success with this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
    var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollValue > 120) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('affix');
    } else{
        $('.navbar').removeClass('affix');
    }
});
```

This will apply the class to the navbar when scrolling down, but will also remove the class when scrolling back up. Previously, when scrolling back up, the applied class would stay applied to the navbar.

Answer (score 2):

As per Vucko's quote within the Mirgation docs, [ScrollPos-Styler](https://github.com/acch/scrollpos-styler) library suited me quite well.

1. Include the `.js ScrollPos-Styler` (`scrollPosStyler.js`) file to your page.
2. Find the relevant `<div>` you wish to make 'sticky'

`<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md">`

3. Apply `sps sps--abv` class

`<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md sps sps--abv">`

4. Add `.css` styles you wish to have triggered once the element has become sticky (As per the [demo page](https://github.com/acch/scrollpos-styler/blob/master/demo/demo.css).

---

```
/** 
 * 'Shared Styles' 
**/
.sps {

}

/** 
 * 'Sticky Above' 
 *
 * Styles you wish to apply
 * Once stick has not yet been applied
**/
.sps--abv {
   padding: 10px
}

/** 
 * 'Sticky Below' 
 *
 * Styles you wish to apply
*  Once stick has been applied
**/
.sps--blw {
   padding: 2px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
    var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset = $('[data-spy="affix"]').attr('data-offset-top');
    if (scrollValue > offset) {
        $('[data-spy="affix"]').addClass('affix-top');
        var width = $('[data-spy="affix"]').parent().width();
        $('.affix-top').css('width', width);
    } else{
        $('[data-spy="affix"]').removeClass('affix-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your answer

Comment: exp Bootstrap 3, attr data-spy="affix" and data-offset-top="number".

Answer (score 1):

For the users who are looking for an answer in pure Javascript, this is how you can do it by using pure Javascript:

```
window.onscroll = (e) => {
    let scrollValue = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollValue > 120) {
        document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.add('affix');
    } else{
        document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.remove('affix');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap 4 there is special class for that.
Try removing the `data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="90"` attributes, and just add 'sticky-top'.

[documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#sticky-top)

Comment: I was having the issue 3 years ago. But thanks for your answer. It will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After trying every solution I could find (and being aware that affix was removed from bootstrap 4), the only way I could get the desired sticky results I needed was to use [sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/).

This is s really simple jQuery plugin that was easy to set-up.

Just include the code in your project and then assign the element you want to stick with

```
$("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();
```

Comment: The point is that I couldn't get the suggested 8 lines to work. I'm not exactly a noob with JS or CSS either. Besides, 8 lines would be a minimum, there are other factors to take into consideration such as different types of scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

simple use class fixed-top in bootstrap 4 and use addClass and removeClass

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollValue > 70) {
         $('.navbar-sticky').addClass('fixed-top');
    }else{
       $('.navbar-sticky').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469634/5247564, The same answer is posted.