# offcanvas-sidebar bootstrap 4 sticky sidebar

Tags: sidebar, sticky, bootstrap-4, off-canvas-menu

hi i recenty used the bootstrap 4 offcanvas template to build my website

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/#

now i want to make my side-bar follow as the users scrolls but bootstrap removed the affix class and recommends using css position sticky. I tried to do this and target the sidebar but it screws up the layout. targeting the .nav doesnt work either

Html

```
<div class="container-fluid header navbar-fixed-top">        
    <div class="row">
           <div class="hidden-md-up col-xs-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">                        
                <img src="images/logo.gif" class="img-fluid center-block" alt="emblem">                        
           </div>
    </div>   
</div><!-- /HEADER -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#area">Locations</a>     
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#deals">Deals</a>     
                </li>                   
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /Navigation -->


            <section id="home">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <img src="images/mazda2.gif" alt="Mazda2" class="img-fluid center-block">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 col-xs-12 text-xs-center">                        
                        <h3>Perth, Western Australia</h3>                           
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section><!-- HOME -->

            <section id="about">
                <div class="about-me">
                    <h3>About Us</h3>

                </div>
            </section><!-- ABOUT -->

    </div><!--ROW -->       
</div><!-- CONTAINER-FLUID -->
```

CSS

```
 /*
 * Style tweaks
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}
body {
  padding-top: 7em;
  position: relative;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
            transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }

   .row-offcanvas-left {
    left: 0;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-right {
    right: 0;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
  left: -33%; /* 4 columns */
  }

  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -33%; /* 4 columns */
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
     left: 33%; /* 4 columns */
   }

   .row-offcanvas-right.active {
     right: 33%; /* 4 columns */
   }

   .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%; /* 4 columns */

  }
}

/*
  * Custom Style
  * --------------------------------------------------
  */

  #sidebar {
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    height:100vh;
 }

  .header {
     background-color: #232323;
 }

 .btn-secondary {
     background-color: #232323;
     border-color: #232323;
     margin-top:0.3em;
 }

 /*
  * HOME
  */

 #home {
   background-color: #434343;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
 }
```

It probably got something to do with my sidebar-off canvas and sidebar position. But without mysidebar position absolute my section contents gets pushed down. I triedremoving itandusing col-x-x class but no go :(

Comment: Im considering using media query and position fixed on my sidebar but thats feel like a bit of a hack and who knows  if i';ll run into other problems ;(

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-offcanvas .nav-stacked {
   position: fixed;
   top: 8em;
   width: 33%;
  } 
}
```

Read more about `position: fixed` at: [Affix is not working in Bootstrap 4 alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349879/bootstrap-4-affix-is-not-working)