# Getting affix to work with bootstrap 4

Tags: affix, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm doing an attempt of getting the affix.js to work with bootstrap 4.
Here is the official js:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/affix.js

This works for example:

```
#foo.affix {
  top: 20px;
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

But there is a strange jump to the left.
Does affix needs a bunch of css as well? Cause I can't find anything relating to affix in the repository.

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/df8tb/2715/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must add the CSS to handle the `affix-top`, `affix` and `affix-bottom` positions.

> Use the affix plugin via data attributes or manually with your own
>   JavaScript. In both situations, you must provide CSS for the
>   positioning and width of your affixed content.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

You're seeing a jump because `position:fixed` takes the element out of the normal document flow so you must postion it and set height, width, etc.. accordingly in the CSS.

**Update:**

The Affix component has been removed from Bootstrap 4, so now you must use a browser with position:sticky support, or jQuery/JS similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147077/171456)