# How to create a fixed header on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a fixed header on scroll, similar to this website:
[www.avauntmagazine.com](http://www.avauntmagazine.com)

This is my html for my header:

```
<div class="bloc bgc-wild-blue-yonder l-bloc " id="bloc-1">
    <div class="container bloc-sm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light row navbar-expand-md flex-column" role="navigation">
                    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="index.html">Company</a>
                    <button id="nav-toggle" type="button" class="ui-navbar-toggler navbar-toggler border-0 p-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-32491" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-32491">
                        <ul class="site-navigation nav navbar-nav mx-auto justify-content-center">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Professional Wedding Planners | Devon</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be using Bootstrap and that has utilities for what you want.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Use the [position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) in CSS:

```
#bloc-1 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would probably use CSS position sticky. That way it will only sticky to the top once it hits the top of the window.

```
#bloc-1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the affix method -  you can do this with some javascript. The Boostrap 4 docs mention using the position: sticky; solution.

[Affix is not working in Bootstrap 4 (alpha)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349879/affix-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-4-alpha)